# CentOS 7 + PHP7 -- php not rendering in browser

Tags: apache, centos7, php-7

I have a clean install of apache/httpd and php7.1.0 running on CentOS 7.

When I execute from the command line:

```
php -v
```

I get the expected response:

```
PHP 7.1.0 (cli) (built: Dec  1 2016 08:13:15) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

But when I try to hit my phpinfo.php page, all I get is...
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>` literally outputted to the screen - can someone tell me what I'm missing, did I forget to enable a mod?

[image]

Comment: Well, looks like php is not activated inside your http server.

Comment: Either it is not installed (note that CLI and http server module are _separate_ packages) or it simply is not activated in the http server configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that PHP isn't enabled in Apache. PHP addresses that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) - step 8 should solve your problem.

As an addition: what I usually do on a new install, is install an entire LAMP-server. On Ubuntu, that's done with `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` (note: the caret is not a typo).

Comment: sweet that did the trick...

It's frustrating that this wasn't done automatically...

Comment: just a note: apt-get is for debian-based systems, not for CentOS ^^

Answer (score 5):

For PHP 7 (May apply to previous versions as well), but I had to do this:

Add this to the bottom of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
or for Centos /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

Answer (score 5):

Fabien's answer worked for me, but apache started to serve css/js files with the wrong mime type. I fixed it adding this at the end of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solution for me - adding this line into httpd.conf where your app's ServerName and DocumentRoot are:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/laravel/public/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the "Directory" line in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf file. Then restart the httpd server
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same problem. On a Centos 8 Stream installation.

First check if php is installed and working, for example:

```
php /var/www/html/info.php
```

If this works, and apache is not serving/interpreting the php file, than install php-fpm (mod_php was deprecated):

```
dnf install php-fpm
systemctl enable php-fpm
systemctl status php-fpm
systemctl restart httpd
```

Check in the browser.
If successful, delete the `info.php` file